# log4j2 achieve folder file owner and permission

Tags: log4j, log4j2

hi i have a distributed application which is deployed on 3 nodes.
I am using log4j2 for logging, the problem is the rolling file appender creates the achieve folder
with owner as root on 2 of the nodes and on 3rd node it gets created with owner as the one with which application is executed.

I want the archieve folder to get created on all nodes with the user which i used when deploying the application
I see filePermissions, fileOwner as few parameters that can be used, but don't want to hard code the fileOwner in my log4j2.properties file.

Any suggestion please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-tested this, the issue was because someone manually created these folder with root access